# iOS: External Display AVPlayerController Dismiss Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, external, display

I'm having the same problem as this question but I don't see where I'm going wrong.

It still remains on the last frame of the video on the external display.

[iOS Swift App AVPlayerController dismiss not working on external display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353247/ios-swift-app-avplayercontroller-dismiss-not-working-on-external-display)

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points to comment on the other question.

Is it because I don't have an AVPlayerItem?

```
let fourVideoViewController = AVPlayerViewController()    

@IBAction func fourVideoPlayButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let fourVideoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Four Animation", 
withExtension: "mov")!
    let fourPlayer = AVPlayer(url: fourVideoURL as URL)

    fourVideoViewController.player = fourPlayer

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: 
NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: 
fourVideoViewController.player?.currentItem)

    self.present(fourVideoViewController, animated: true) {
        self.fourVideoViewController.player!.play()
    }
}


@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {

    fourVideoViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    fourVideoViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928273/automatically-dismiss-avplayer-when-video-completes-from-all-screens/53928615#53928615

Comment: Yes @Bappaditya couldn’t get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to dismiss inside your `playerDidFinishPlaying` function

`self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

OR

`self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Still no luck. The 2nd option gave me the error Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`fourVideoViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
fourVideoViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`